Choose available GPU devices with device_map
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    device_map="cuda:3",
)

There are many GPUs on the server, but I can only use two of them. How should I configure device_map (or other parameters) so that the model runs on both GPUs?

First thing is that you can use device_map="auto", it means that the model uses the available resources in the system.
But if you want to use only 2 specific GPU's in the system, so now device_map={"0": "cuda:<GPU_id>", "1": "cuda:<GPU_id>", .... so on (if any) }.
Or add other parameter named device_ids=[<GPU_id>, <GPU_id>, ... so on (if any)] instead of device_map parameter.
So now if you don't know the GPU ids so then perform several ways:


import torch
print(torch.cuda.device_ids()) #it shows all GPU's ids.



import torch
print(torch.cuda.device_count())
for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
    print(f"GPU {i}: {torch.cuda.get_device_name(i)}")



See GPU ids using this and then perform above operation.

That was a lot simpler than I thought, thank you. Can I ask you, though, where can I find this information? I just can't seem to find the documentation about this functionality, only some guides without a complete list of options.
